# How to get the ReturnType for a UseQuery definition

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make a generic TypeScript wrapper for RTKQ queries. The last piece of that goal that I am stuck on is getting the return type for a generic, or even specific, query. Below I will include some of the main lines of code in my test but [here is a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtkq-demo-cgwsjt?file=/src/test.ts) which shows my full code.

```
type EndpointKey = keyof typeof api.endpoints;
type Endpoint<EndpointName extends EndpointKey> = typeof injectedAPI.endpoints[EndpointName];
type ReturnQuery<E extends EndpointKey> = Endpoint<E>["useQuery"];

// Type is Record<string, any> & UseQuerySubscriptionResult<> - where is the UseQueryStateResult<> at? Might not be relevant but seems suspicious.
type PuppiesQueryReturnType = ReturnType<ReturnQuery<"getPuppies">>;

const queryReturn: PuppiesQueryReturnType = {} as PuppiesQueryReturnType;
const { data, foo, refetch, isLoading, error } = queryReturn; // All values have type any except for refetch
```

I am not sure if this is a potential bug in the types for RTKQ or if there is some step I am missing or doing incorrectly.

Note: Not all of this is my original code. Much of it is copied from various posts across the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer to my problems is the Type `TypedUseQueryHookResult` from `@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react/buildHooks`. I can't find a reference to it in the docs but if anyone has the link please comment and I will update.

Using this I can do something like

```
type QueryResultInfered<E extends EndpointKey> = Endpoint<E> extends ApiEndpointQuery<
  QueryDefinition<infer QueryArgs, infer BaseQuery, any, infer ResultType>,
  any
>
  ? TypedUseQueryHookResult<ResultType, QueryArgs, BaseQuery>
  : never;
```

there might be a simpler way to do this without the inference but this will do the trick.

Thanks to acemarke on the Reactiflux Discord for the help!